# Segmentation Fault when using memcpy with void pointers - C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc, memcpy

So I've been creating a doubly linked generic list in C. I have successfully created it with ints as the data stored but now I need to make it generic.

I have created a list and node variable type:

```
struct node{

  struct node *prev;
  struct node *next;
  void *item;

};

struct list{

  struct node *first;
  struct node *current;
  struct node *last;
  int itemSize;

};
```

I am having issues with inserting values into item in the node. I have the following code to insert a newNode before the current pointer.

```
void insertBefore(list *l, void *p){

  struct node *new = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  new->item = malloc(l->itemSize);

  memcpy(new->item,p,l->itemSize);

...
```

Void pointer p is some data and itemSize is the number of bytes of said data. Of course this is not the whole insertBefore code, but the logic in that should be sound as I have made the list work with int as the type of item.

When I call this I get a Segmentation fault: 11 error and I am not sure why.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

edit:

I've included some of the other code called as that might be where stuff is going back, although the seg fault is at the `memcpy` in `insertBefore`

```
list *newList(int b){

  list *l = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
  l->itemSize = b;
  l->first = NULL;
  l->current = NULL;
  l->last = NULL;

  return l;
}
```

and then this is called in the main:

```
list *l = newList(sizeof(int));
insertBefore(l, (void *)3);
...
```

Comment: Why not just let the user of your list worry about allocating and deallocating their data? Pigeonholing them into using `malloc` to store data is severely limiting. Just demand a valid data pointer when you inset into the list, as well a callback for releasing the data when creating list object.

Comment: I'm trying to create a library module so that it can be reused later where the user does not see nodes or anything and only moves forward and backwards between data as they need, keeping it as simple as possible for them.

Comment: (Also I did not create the idea for this, I have just been told I need to make it, I do fully agree with you!)

Comment: The code shown is not the problem. The root-cause must be in the code you do  *not* show us, running beforehand.

Comment: Also in C there is *no* need to cast the result of `malloc`& friends nor is it recommended in any way.

Comment: Does by any chance the code run on 64 bit *and* misses to include `<stdlib.h>` *and* does not prototype `malloc()` properly?

Comment: I have '<stdlib.h>' included and malloc is being called with an int in it, I'm going to have a look at where else in the code it could possible be going wrong

Comment: What is `void *item` in this case?

Comment: It's an int, its from this call `insertBefore(l,(void *)3)`, l is a list that has been initialised already

Comment: Why not just use `int item`? It would be easier to use.

Comment: I have created it for item already, and it is much easier, but unfortunately my assignment asks for generic lists

Comment: I've edited the question to include extra code

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). **use the debugger** (`gdb`) & `valgrind`

Comment: You are passing `3` as an address! How could this work out? Change `insertBefore(l,(void *)3)` to either be `int i=3; insertBefore(l, &i)` or to `insertBefore(l, &((int){3}))`

Comment: As rule of thumb: If you see yourself confronted with the (seemingly) need to cast (silence down the compiler) in C, think twice or triple what could be wrong. There are very rare cases where you *need* to cast in C.

Comment: Thank you for the help alk, using an address instead of an int (duh!) makes everything work perfectly, I'll keep your advice in mind for the future

Answer (score 1):

Your code attempts to `memcpy(new->item, 3, sizeof(int))` 
You are getting segmentation fault because 3 is not a dereference able address.

Instead, you should do this:

```
int x = 3;
insertBefore(l, &x);
```